# macOS NSDistributedNotification: fprint or NSLog value of a specific key in userInfo?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications

I have an app that sends out the following **NSDistributed Notification**, parts of which I eventually want to "grab" with a CLI and pipe it to a shell script:

```
{name = TheApplicationNotification; object = TheApplicationNotification; userInfo = {
    path = "/path/to/a/file";
}}
```

I don't really know anything about programming, but I managed to grab the whole notification with the following code for a **small CLI**, shamelessly put together from two older stackoverflow comments:

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
#import <Foundation/NSNotification.h>
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
#import <Foundation/NSDistributedNotificationCenter.h>
#import <Foundation/NSRunLoop.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface monitorcli: NSObject {}
-(id) init;
-(void) receive: (NSNotification*) notification;
@end

@implementation monitorcli
-(id) init {
  NSDistributedNotificationCenter * center
    = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

  [center addObserver: self
          selector:    @selector(receive:)
          name:        @"TheApplicationNotification"
          object:      nil
  ];
  fprintf(stderr,"Listening...\n");
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
  fprintf(stderr,"Stopping...\n");
  return self;
}
-(void) receive: (NSNotification*) notification {
  NSLog(@"%@", notification);
}
@end

int main( int argc, char ** argv) {
  [[monitorcli alloc] init];
  return 0;
}
```

I have also managed to just get the **notification name** by substituting

```
NSLog(@"%@", notification);
```

for

```
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", [[notification name] UTF8String] );
```

My question now is: what changes in the code are necessary to **only print the "path" key in userInfo**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSLog(@"%@", notification.userInfo[@"path"]);
```

The `.userInfo` Gets the value of the `userInfo` property, this value is a dictionary. The `[@"path"]` then gets the value associated with the `@"path"` key in the dictionary.

*Note: all code typed directly into answer, expect minor typos.*

Comment: It works great if you add `#import <Foundation/NSDictionary.h>`. Thank you!